# form_for save input values to session variables

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to create a compare functionality for an index of schools. Currently I am using the following code which takes any checked school and adds it to the school_ids[] in the params.

In my gemfile:

```
  gem 'will_paginate'
```

In my school's index.html.erb:

```
  <%= form_tag compare_path, :method => 'get' do %>
    <%= submit_tag "Compare" %> 
    <ul>
      <% @schools.each do |school| %>
        <li>
        <%= check_box_tag'school_ids[]', school.id %>
        <%= link_to school.name, school %><br>
        <%= school.city %>, <%= school.state %>
        </li>
      <% end %>
    </ul>
  <% end %>
```

In my school controller I have:

```
  def compare
    @schools = School.find(params[:school_ids])
  end
```

This works great as long as all of the check schools are on the same page. But since I'm using will_paginate to paginate the list of schools, if I change pages, the check boxes do not persist. I'm assuming I need to save to sessions somehow.

Comment: I haven't used that gem but I'm it looks like it adds the page numbers with links at the bottom, each link generating a request.  Is that request handled via ajax or a normal post?

Comment: I don't have time to look it up, but I'm 100% sure there's a way to pass other params to will paginate.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you want to be able to add a check mark to a school A on page 1 of the index, go to page 2 of the index and add another check mark for school B, then submit the compare form and see schools A and B? If that's the case, then you're correct, you need to get the check boxes into the session. Attach a js click event, like

```
$('.checkbox_class').click(function(){
    $.post('update_session_method', { school_id: $(this).val(), checked: $(this).is(:checked)]);
});
```

then add a controller method

```
def update_session_method
  session[:school_ids] ||= []
  if params[:checked]
    session[:school_ids] << params[:school_id]
  else
    session[:school_ids].delete(params[:school_id])
  end
end
```

then your compare method

```
def compare
  @schools = School.find(params[:school_ids].merge(session[:school_ids] || []))
end
```